# Zip Three Different Mono of Different Type and return response in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, kotlin

I want to make async two webclient calls.
And then wait two responses, use some business logic and return some value.
Below code is simple version of what I wrote.
However I'm not sure it is good code or not.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/{userId}"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
fun getRoomList(@PathVariable("userId") userId: String): RoomDto.FullInfo {
    
    val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(2)
    val roomPriceSumListMono = Room.getRoomPriceSumMono(webClient, roomPriceSumDto) //remote call

    roomPriceSumListMono.subscribe {
        //some logic
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }

    val userListInRoomListMono = roomService.getUserListInRoomListMonoFromRemote(webClient, userIdListInRoomList) //remote call       
    var userListInRoomList: List<List<UserDto.Info>>? = null
    userListInRoomListMono.subscribe{
        //some logic
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }
    
    countDownLatch.await()
    return RoomDto.FullInfo(roomInfoList, userListInRoomList, userRoomCap, maxRoomCount)
}
```

I tried to use `Mono.zip` but I couldn't use it like below.

```
Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, (m1, m2) -> {
    //some login
    return RoomDto.FullInfo(roomInfoList, userListInRoomList, userRoomCap, maxRoomCount)
}
```

Is there better way to wait async `WebClient` calls and then return some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I might rework this answer if you add details about your errors, because i'm only doing a rough guess of your problems here.

Zip is indeed the right operator for your use case. In your second example, the syntax is java-one, so it cannot work in Kotlin because:

1. Lambda syntax differs (parameters should be declared after brackets)
2. `return` in lambdas does not mean *return from lambda*. To return a value from a lambda, you should just call that value in the last line of the lambda.

More information about lambda syntax in [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions)

Otherwise, you should let Spring Webflux handle the pipeline, and enclose the return value of your first function in a Mono. Once done, you should be able to use zip operator:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/{userId}"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
fun getRoomList(@PathVariable("userId") userId: String): Mono<RoomDto.FullInfo> {
    
    val roomPriceSumListMono = Room.getRoomPriceSumMono(webClient, roomPriceSumDto)
    val userListInRoomListMono = roomService.getUserListInRoomListMonoFromRemote(webClient, userIdListInRoomList)

    return roomPriceSumListMono
            .zipWith(userListInRoomListMono) {
                roomPriceList, userListInRoomList -> 
                    RoomDto.FullInfo(roomInfoList, userListInRoomList, userRoomCap, maxRoomCount)
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm busy now so I didn't tested you code but I think it's helpful.

Comment: It seems parentheses in your lambda expression should be removed.
`return roomPriceSumListMono
            .zipWith(userListInRoomListMono) { roomPriceList, userListInRoomList -> 
                    RoomDto.FullInfo(roomInfoList, userListInRoomList, userRoomCap, maxRoomCount)
            }`

Comment: After removing the parentheses it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed it. Happy to ear it solves your problem.

Comment: No problem. I didn't know that lambda syntax in kotlin is different compared to java. You saved my day. Thanks again.